# Using unique locks while in DPC

Tags: c++, multithreading, kernel, locking, ndis

Currently working on a light weight filter in the NDIS stack. I'm trying to inject a packet which set in a global variable as an NBL. During receive NBL, if an injected NBL is pending, than a lock is taken by the thread before picking the injected NBL up to process it. Originally I was looking at using a spin lock or FAST_MUTEX. But according to the documentation for FAST_MUTEX, any other threads attempting to take the lock will wait for the lock to release before continuing.

The problem is, that receive NBL is running in DPC mode. This would cause a DPC running thread to pause and wait for the lock to release. Additionally, I'd like to be able to assert ownership of a thread's ownership over a lock.

My question is, does windows kernel support unique mutex locks in the kernel, can these locks be taken in DPC mode and how expensive is assertion of ownership in the lock. I'm fairly new to C++ so forgive any syntax errors.

I attempted to define a mutex in the LWF object

```cpp
// Header file

#pragma once
#include <mutex.h>

class LWFobject
{
public:
  LWFobject()
  std::mutex ExampleMutex;
  std::unique_lock ExampleLock;
}

//=============================================
// CPP file
#include "LWFobject.h"

LWFobject::LWFObject()
{
  ExmapleMutex = CreateMutex( 
        NULL,
        FALSE,    
        NULL); 
  ExampleLock(ExampleMutex, std::defer_lock);
}
```

Is the use of unique_locks supported in the kernel? When I attempt to compile it, it throws hundreds of compilation errors when attempting to use mutex.h. I'd like to use `try_lock` and `owns_lock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use standard ISO C++ synchronization mechanisms while inside a Windows kernel.

A Windows kernel is a whole other world in itself, and requires you to live by its rules (which are vast - see for example these two 700-page books: [1](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-internals-part-1-9780735648739), [2](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-internals-part-2-9780735665873)).

Processing inside a Windows kernel is largely asynchronous and event-based; you handle events and schedule deferred calls or use other [synchronization techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/synchronization-techniques) for work that needs to be done later.

Having said that, it *is* possible to have a mutex in the traditional sense inside a Windows driver. It's called a [Fast Mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/fast-mutexes-and-guarded-mutexes) and requires raising IRQL to APC_LEVEL. Then you can use calls like [ExAcquireFastMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff544337(v=vs.85)), [ExTryToAcquireFastMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff545647(v=vs.85)) and [ExReleaseFastMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff545549(v=vs.85)) to lock/try-lock/release it.

Comment: That's generally true, but keep in mind that you cannot use *any* wait/sleep primitive while at DISPATCH_LEVEL, which includes the NDIS datapath.  That rules out any sort of mutex.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental property of a lock is which priority (IRQL) it's synchronized at.  A lock can be acquired from lower priorities, but can never be acquired from a higher priority.

(Why?  Imagine how the lock is implemented.  The lock must raise the current task priority up to the lock's natural priority.  If it didn't do this, then a task running at a low priority could grab the lock, get pre-empted by a higher priority task, which would then deadlock if it tried to acquire the same lock.  So every lock has a documented natural IRQL, and the lock will first raise the current thread to that IRQL before attempting to acquire exclusivity.)

The NDIS datapath can run at any IRQL between PASSIVE_LEVEL and DISPATCH_LEVEL, inclusive.  This means that anything on the datapath must only ever use locks that are synchronized at DISPATCH_LEVEL (or higher).  This really limits your choices: you can use KSPIN_LOCKs, NDIS_RW_LOCKs, and a handful of other uncommon ones.

This gets viral: if you have one function that can sometimes run at DISPATCH_LEVEL (like the datapath), it forces the lock to be synchronized at DISPATCH_LEVEL, which forces any other functions that hold the lock to also run at DISPATCH_LEVEL.  That can be inconvenient, for example you might want to hold the locks while reading from the registry too.

There are various approaches to design your driver:
* Use spinlocks everywhere.  When reading from the registry, read into temporary variables, then grab a spinlock and copy the temporary variables into global state.
* Use mutexes (or better yet: pushlocks) everywhere.  Quarantine the datapath into a component that runs at dispatch level, and carefully copy any configuration state into this component's private state.
* Somehow avoid having your datapath interact with the rest of your driver, so there's no shared state, and thus no shared locks.
* Have the datapath rush to PASSIVE_LEVEL by queuing all packets to a worker thread.